# On Click Pop Up Box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I replicate what [this site](http://rapgenius.com/Eminem-rap-god-lyrics) does. Could I replicate the pop up boxes using pure CSS or would HTML have to be involved? Sorry for the lack of detail but I'm just learning.

Comment: You should start with the basics. Learn HTMl and CSS, then we can help you. If we just give you some random code you will never learn. Go to w3schools.com and follow some tutorials.

Comment: You can render the page source and analyze it. I guess this is generated with CSS, HTML and probably some JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what yo define a 'pop-up box' is. If you want a simple alert with an 'ok' button, straight JavaScript would do. Otherwise, some form of modal window would probably be best. Modals are pretty good at what they do, and is in fact what the site you provided uses. They are made up of JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. Honestly, since you are just starting out, I would recommend finding a HTML tutorial, and learn how all three of these languages go together before tackling a modal.